# Visual Studio, add connected service does not register app in azure AD

Tags: visual-studio-2013, office365, azure-active-directory

I followed the steps as per 
https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-WebApp-MultiTenant and added the connected service.  However this does not register the app under Windows Azure Active Directory Applications.  I have properly linked my office 365 account into Azure.  However when I add the connected service it is still empty.  Is this a known issue and what is the work around?

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't a known issue. The "Add Connected Service" wizard is not generating a client ID and secret in your `web.config`?

As a workaround you could login to the Azure Management Portal and [register the app manually](https://github.com/jasonjoh/office365-azure-guides/blob/master/RegisterAnAppInAzure.md), then put the client ID and secret into your `web.config`.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue and spend some hours on it. Finally it turns out that I had used a user account to log in in visual studio that was assigned to a different MS Azure account.

In my case I was using the user of production environment instead of my own developer account to log in.